# Javascript html to pdf - remove table borders

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfmake

I'm fiddling around with a way to build light pdf-prints of my table(s). I've got an output but I can't seem to get rid of the borders and even after a lot of googling and trial and error I still stand where I started. Anyone who knows pdfmake.js enough to point out where I've gone wrong?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz6L3yg8/27/)

```
var externalDataRetrievedFromServer = [
{ Avdelning: 'First', Namn1: 104.44,Namn2: 78.8, Namn3:83.89,Namn4:25.64,Namn5:20.56},
{ Avdelning: 'Second', Namn1: 66.48,Namn2: 61.59, Namn3:77.41,Namn4:4.89,Namn5:-10.93},
{ Avdelning: 'Third', Namn1: 56.2,Namn2: 46.2, Namn3:56.3,Namn4:10.01,Namn5:-0.09},
{ Avdelning: 'Fourth', Namn1: 77.22,Namn2: 61.41, Namn3:87.72,Namn4:15.81,Namn5:-10.5},
{ Avdelning: 'Fifth', Namn1: 75.78,Namn2: 68.8, Namn3:77.11,Namn4:6.97,Namn5:-1.33},
{ Avdelning: 'Sixth', Namn1: 67.47,Namn2: 47.58, Namn3:81.26,Namn4:19.9,Namn5:-13.79},
{ Avdelning: 'Seventh', Namn1: 94.57,Namn2: 74.21, Namn3:77.16,Namn4:20.35,Namn5:17.41},
{ Avdelning: 'Eighth', Namn1: 62.03,Namn2: 53.95, Namn3:57,Namn4:8.08,Namn5:5.03},
{ Avdelning: 'Ninth', Namn1: 53.89,Namn2: 34.92, Namn3:68.33,Namn4:18.97,Namn5:-14.44},
{ Avdelning: 'Tenth', Namn1: 55.06,Namn2: 36.09, Namn3:52.72,Namn4:18.97,Namn5:2.33}, ]; 

function buildTableBody(data, columns) {
var body = [];

body.push(columns);

data.forEach(function(row) {
    var dataRow = [];

    columns.forEach(function(column) {
        dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
    })

    body.push(dataRow);
});

return body;}

function table(data, columns) {
return {
    table: {
        headerRows: 1,
        body: buildTableBody(data, columns),
        layout: {hLineColor: function(i, node) {return (i < node.table.body.length) ? 'white' : 'white'; },
        vLineColor: function(i, node) { return (i < node.table.widths.length) ? 'white' : 'white';}
        }
    }
};
}

var dd = {
content: [
    { text: 'Dat:', fontSize: 14, bold: true, margin: [0, 20, 0, 8] },

    table(externalDataRetrievedFromServer, ['Avdelning', 'Namn1', 'Namn2', 'Namn3', 'Namn4', 'Namn5'])]


};

$('#download').click(function () {
   pdfMake.createPdf(dd).download("test.pdf");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some furious(more) testing I finally found what was wrong - and it was the simplest thing. I had gotten the layout-part inside the table brackets, were it didn't do anything (no error message either).

In this example I have removed all borders

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz6L3yg8/47/)

```
function table(data, columns) {
    return {
        table: {
                    headerRows: 1,
                    body: buildTableBody(data, columns)
                },
            layout: 'noBorders'

    };
}
```